# integer ordered pair,s $(x,y)$ in $1!+2!+3!+............+x! =y^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(1) Total no. of integer ordered pair,s $(x,y)$ in $1!+2!+3!+............+x! =y^2$

(2) Total no. of integer ordered pair,s $(x,y)$ in $1!+2!+3!+............+x! =y^3$

(3) Total no. of integer ordered pair,s $(x,y)$ in $1!+2!+3!+............+x! =y^4$

where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}.$

$\underline{\bf{My\;Try}}::$ for (1) one:: If $x\geq 4.$ Then $(1!+2!+3!+......+x!)$ conatin last digit is $ 3$

and we know that square of any integer does not have last digit is $3$.

So $x<4$, So we will check for $x = 1,2,3$.

If $x=1$, Then $y^2=1\Rightarrow y = 1$. So integer ordered pairs $(1,1)$.

If $x=2$, Then $y^2=3\Rightarrow y = \sqrt{3}$. So no integer ordered pairs.

If $x=3$, Then $y^2=9\Rightarrow y = 3$. So integer ordered pairs $(3,3)$.

So for (1) one integer ordered pair,s is $(x,y) = (1,1)\;\;,(3,3)$

But I did not understand how can i solve (2) and (3) one,

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: It does not strike for me immediately how can you say  $(1!+2!+3!+......+x!)$ contains last digit $3$.. could you please elaborate that...

Comment: Q3 is a subset of Q1, so that's done too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Q1, you have already noticed that for $x = 4$, the LHS ends in $3$, and for $x > 4$, the terms that are added have last digit $0$.  As no square ends in $3$, we do not have any solution for $x \ge 4$.

For Q2, note that if $x \ge 9$, the LHS is divisible by $3$, so if this is the cube of an integer, that integer must also be divisible by $3$.  In fact the power must be divisible by $27$.  But $1! + 2! + ... + 8! \equiv 9 \pmod {27}$, hence there are no solutions for $x \ge 9$.

For Q3, you could notice that a fourth power is also a square and hence apply the answer to Q1, or extend the argument of Q2 (which in fact holds true for any larger power).

Comment: To Thanks for solution, but i did not understand (II) one, could you explain me one more time.

Comment: $1! + 2! + ... + 8!=46233$ is divisible by $3$.  As all larger factorials are divisible by $3\times 9=27$, we have LHS is divisible by $3$ in all such cases.  Hence RHS must also be divisible by $3$, and hence it must be divisible by $3^3=27$. But LHS has remainder $9$ when dividing by $27$, as $46233$ is not a multiple. Hence it cannot work for any $x \ge 9$.