# proof - Show that $1! +2! +3!+\cdots+n!$ is a perfect power if and only if $n=3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial, perfect-powers

> Show that $1! +2! +3!+\cdots+n!$ is a perfect power if and only if $n =3$

For $n=3$, $1!+2!+3!=9=3^2$. I also feel that the word 'power' makes it a whole lot hard to prove. How do we prove this? What technique do we use?

I don't have any idea how to proceed with this. I would love some hints.

Comment: It's supposed to be $m^k$ with $k>1$?

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes.

Comment: I expect this was inspired from the problem that asked for the solutions where $1!+2!+3!+\dots+n!$ is a square.

Comment: Similar to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525613/integer-ordered-pair-s-x-y-in-123-x-y3/525755

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$1!+2!+\dots + 8! \equiv 9\pmod{27}$, and any additional term you add is $\equiv 0 \pmod{27}$.

So there can be no larger power than $2$ when $n \ge 8$, as $3$ is a factor but $27$ is not.

There can be no square either for $n> 3$, as $1!+2!+3!+4!=33$ and all additional terms have last digit $0$, and no square ends in a $3$.

The remaining finite cases are easily checked.

Comment: for $k \geq 9, k !$ is a multiple of $27,$ while $1 !+2 !+$ $\cdots+8 !$ is a multiple of $9,$ but not $27 .$ Hence $1 !+2 !+\cdots+n !$ cannot be a cube or higher power..i did not understand why it cannot be a cube or higher power if it is a multiple of 9 but not 27, can you pls clear my doubt.

Comment: @ishan If a cube is divisible by a prime $p$, (in this case $p=3$) it must be divisible by $p^3$.  Work it out or be more specific in where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Note that,$$1! + 2! + 3! + 4! = 33$$
$$1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! = 153$$
$$1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6! = 873 \ldots $$
The last digit of the numbers is $3$ (This is happening because for $n>4$ the last digit of $n!$ is $0$). Now for a number to be a perfect square the last digit should be one of the digits $1,4,5,6,9$. Hence for $n>3$, $\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {i!} $ cannot be a perfect square.