# What is $x$, if $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + (x-1)! + x! = k^2$ and $k$ is an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, quadratics, factorial

> What is $x$, if $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + (x-1)! + x! = k^2$ and $k$ is an integer?

Using trial and error, it is obvious that for $x < 4$, the given equation has solutions only for $x = 1,k = \pm1$ and $x=3, k = \pm 3$. Where to go from here?

Comment: A more general question is handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702813/proof-show-that-1-2-3-cdotsn-is-a-perfect-power-if-and-only-if-n-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be proved that for $x \ge 4$, no solutions exist. The expressions

$$\begin{aligned}1! + 2! + 3! + 4! &= 33 \\
1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! &= 153 \\
1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6! &= 873 \\ 
1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6! + 7! &= 5913\end{aligned}$$
end with the digit $3$. Now, for $x \ge 4$ the last digit of the sum $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + x!$ is equal to 3 and therefore, this sum cannot be equal to a square of a whole number $k$ (because the square of a whole number cannot end with $3$).

Therefore, $1$ and $3$ are the only solutions for $x$.

Comment: You have given particular samples only. How can we gaurantee that in general "for x≥4 the last digit of the sum 1!+2!+3!+⋯+x! is equal to 3"

Comment: @Mick For $n \ge 5$, $n!$ ends with the digit 0.

Comment: I see what you mean now but if that comment has been included in your post, the deduction will be much clearer.